# Why is (this) & obj used after function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
     (function(obj){
        $.each(Templates.inputs, function(key, value){
            obj.elementsKey.push(key);
            obj.elementsValueType.push(value.type);
        });
     }(this));
```

> why is this (this)) used after function?
>   And What does obj does when used as parameter

Comment: `this`-the context is passed the the IIFE. Two reasons: **1.** `this` inside `each()` refers to the current element in the set **2.** Less scope-chaingin traversing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so-called IIFE - you declare a function and immediatly calling it.
This function has argument `obj`, in which current variable `this` is placed. So, for example, if you run this IIFE inside a global scope, you'll get a `window` object in a `obj` variable inside function.

[More about IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)